# Does a visa run in Taiwan really involve applying for a new visa every time, or just relying on visa-exempt passport entry?

Tags: visa, us-citizens, taiwan

Background: I've lived in Taiwan for 3 years now, always with an ARC (as I've always been employed by a Taiwanese company with the power to apply for an ARC for me up until now). I've applied for a 6th month ARC extension for "seeking work" since I quit my last job, but I won't be getting another job with a company that can apply for a visa for me, so I'm looking to start doing the whole "leave the country every 3 months" thing that I've heard so much about (I am from a visa-exempt country [I'm a US citizen], so from what I understand I can stay in the country for 90 days without an ARC.)

From other answers I've read (Taiwan maximum stay rules with reentry) it would seem that this isn't frowned upon and can be done rather regularly and quickly (in a one-day visa run to HK).

My questions are:

1) Do I have to actually go through a visa application process to do this, or is what I would really by doing just leaving the country and coming back, relying on my passport for 90 day visa-exempt entry?

2) Do I have to go to HK or can I go to any country, like Japan? Would China even count, since they don't like to admit Taiwan is a separate country?

Comment: But if you enter for 90 days under visa waiver - won't you be barred from taking employment then?

Answer (score 4):

1. You can do it without applying for a new visa, but as you said, you would be relying on your 90 days visa exemption period. During that period you will officially be a tourist, which mean you won't be allowed to have a job.
   See this page for details: http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=1443&ctNode=779&mp=2
2. You just need to get out of Taiwan and get back in. I don't know why most people go to HK there are other countries that close, but any country would do. If I remember well, to fly to China you need to pass the immigration and get in the international zone so it should work.